# Creating alternate list elements

Tags: html, css, list

I'm trying to create a list style as shown in the below figure
[image]

I tried to add the bordering but it's coming for the whole structure.

```css
.styled-list {
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.styled-list li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.styled-list li:before {
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  top: 6px;
  left: 0;
}
.styled-list li:nth-child(even) {
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.styled-list li:nth-child(even):before {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="styled-list">
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
  <li>List Item 5</li>
  <li>List Item 6</li>
  <li>List Item 7</li>
  <li>List Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

How can I change the my list to the image shown.

Comment: Where is "HEAD" in the list or outside the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some `:after` pseudo classes, it can be done:

Note that it needs some minor tweaking...

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
.styled-list {
  font-size: 1em;
  list-style: none;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.styled-list li {
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 3em;
  line-height: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
/* move the odd items(expept the first) to the right */
.styled-list li:nth-child(2n+3) {
  margin-left: 60%;
}
/* move the first item (head) to the center */
.styled-list li:first-child {
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
}
/* create the lines to the middle */
.styled-list li:nth-child(even):after,
.styled-list li:nth-child(2n+3):before {
  content: ' ';
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
/* line for the left items */
.styled-list li:nth-child(even):after {
  left:100%;
  right: -25%;
  margin-right: -1px; /* compensate line width */
}
/* line for the right items */
.styled-list li:nth-child(2n+3):before {
  left: -25%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-left: -1px; /* compensate line width */
}
/* horizontal line */
.styled-list:after {
  content: ' ';
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  bottom: 2.5em;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0; /* compensate line width */
}
```

```html
<ul class="styled-list">
  <li>Head</li>
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3 with some more text inside it that can also be in three lines</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
  <li>List Item 5</li>
  <li>List Item 6</li>
  <li>List Item 7</li>
  <li>List Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will use your code and will achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```css
.styled-list {
  position:relative;
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.styled-list:before {
   position:absolute;
   content:" ";
   background:#000;
   top:-10px;
   bottom:10px;
   right:50%;
   width:2px;
   margin-right:-1px;
}
.head {
position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin:0 auto 10px;
  text-align:center;
  max-width:100px;
}
.styled-list li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:inline-block;
}
.styled-list li:nth-child(even) {
  margin-top:20px;
  float:right;
}
.styled-list li:nth-child(even):after {
  content:" ";
  position:absolute;
  width:18px;
  height:2px;
  left:-18px;
  top:50%;
  background:#000;
}
.styled-list li:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.styled-list li:nth-child(odd):after {
  content:" ";
  position:absolute;
  width:18px;
  height:2px;
  right:-18px;
  top:50%;
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">Header</div>
<ul class="styled-list">
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
  <li>List Item 5</li>
  <li>List Item 6</li>
  <li>List Item 7</li>
  <li>List Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If the content is bigger than "List Item .." than your design doesn't fit anymore... https://jsfiddle.net/zs7to9fy/

Comment: yes you are right, i just implemented the idea so he understand the use of before/after element :) then the code need to be updated to the needs ;)